# How to limit iPhone shake gesture detection to specific situation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, accelerometer, shake

I succesfully implemented the shake gesture, but now I would like to limit it to activate only in one specific situation (in the options panel of my app).

- I first created ShakeWindow class which is a subclass of UIWindow. In ShakeWindow I added `- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to register shake gesture.
- Next I went to AppDelegate.m and edited `window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` to use the new ShakeWindow instead of UIWindow.

It works great, but how do I limit it's functionality? I'm just starting Objective-C and consider myself as a novice coder overall so keep that in mind when answering, thank you!

I use Cocos2D as the framework and I don't use Interface Builder if those matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but how about...

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (/* conditions where my app responds to shake */) {
        // respond to shake
    }
    // otherwise, it's like it never happened
}
```

Comment: I must say I sometimes make the easiest things look way harder than they really are. Thank you.